# If replacement-hotkey was preceded by a j, execute the script

Tags: replace, autohotkey

I'm using an AutoHotkey replacement-script to auto-correct my mistakes. However, when I'm gaming, I have to hit 'j' before I can type. I'd it to also work when I type j-hotkey.

So when I type:
`i'd` » I'd, but also when I type `ji'd` » I'd.

Is there a way I can do this without having to make duplicates for everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the AutoHotkey-forum, I got this answer, which works great:

```
:* B0 Z:j::
    return
```

if you want, you can even use it like this to prevent problems when you're not playing:

```
#IfWinActive Battlefield 3™ ;or whatever game you're playing
    :* B0 Z:j::
    return
#IfWinActive ;end of condition
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to replace the 'j' as well? If so, se [Hotstrings](http://www.autohotkey.net/~polyethene/#hotstrings):

```
Hotstrings("j?i'd","I'd")
```

Otherwise, just use the ? option, which will allow your hotstring to trigger even if it's inside another word:

```
:*?:i'd::I'd
```

Comment: Thanks. I can use this for a lot of other words. :3